# Почему find из BeautifulSoup не находит тег?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

не могу понять, почему не находит теги отзывов. по другим тегам все работает.

```js
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

response = requests.get(
    url='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.mail.mailapp&hl=ru&gl=US&showAllReviews=true',
    headers={'user-agent': f'{ua.random}'}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
feedback = soup.find('span', jsname='bN97Pc').text
print(feedback)
```

[image: mail]

Comment: Скорее всего коментарии догружаются после загрузки страницы.

Comment: я тоже так подумал, но первый комментарий точно должен быть. более того, можно загрузить страницу сразу со всеми комментариями, но это не помогает.

Comment: попробуй сохранить полученый html и посмотреть, там будет ясно.PS: возможно параметр jsname динамический а коменарий приходит другой

Comment: странная ерунда, просто не ищет теги.

Comment: в таком случае просто пропарсите через сплиты, или може в доке что то по этому поводу написано будет

Comment: вот что я нашел по этой [теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519595/custom-attributes-in-beautifulsoup/55519978)

Comment: я так понял, что комментарии просто закрыты и так просто не получить доступ к ним, потому что другие данные нормально парсятся. Но как добраться к комментариям, не понял.. Будет интересно если кто-то знающий даст ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я понял, что на странице изначально комментариев нет, их вставляет код на JS, который выполняется браузером. Надо посмотреть предлагает ли гугл API для получения комментариев.
Вот здесь посмотри https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews?hl=ru